# Is there any way to search multiple directories using EnumerateFiles in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, enumerate

I'm searching for specific files in Powershell using EnumerateFiles but can only search one directory at a time:

```
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles(SearchLocation, SearchString, "AllDirectories")
```

Comment: You need to loop through the folders, and then use that method, or even better would be to use the instance method form `IO.DirectoryInfo`. What PowerShell version are you running? Do note that as you have it right now the enumeration will stop at first error

Comment: Any reason you can't use the built-in _Get-ChildItem_ cmdlet in PowerShell as this will do the heavy lifting for you when you specify the _-Recurse_ option?

Comment: I got it figured out, I originally thought EnumerateFiles would be faster but it's pretty much the same as GCI. Thanks everyone.